# i can't open Microsoft office

Tags: libreoffice

i can't open any  How to open DOCX, XLSX & PPTX File in linux , im trying to install liberoffice in my device but i get error while install this application 
anyone can advice me to install any program support this type of application , so by the way my os linux elementary , anyone help me please

Comment: Elementary is of-topic at this site.  http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Libre Office can be found on their website https://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/?version=5.0.0

Also you can get it from accessing your terminal. I am running 14.4 Xubuntu and I downloaded from the website with no errors.

Hope this helps.